# How to launch ChildProcess in Node on MacOSX And Linux

Tags: linux, macos, node.js, express, path

I have a Express server which run the script below fine on Linux box.
Now, would like to change the python file location reference to the a directory structure
on Mac OSX. I need something that references the current working directory in node, but will
work as relative location.  This is a path problem. Similar code to this runs fine on Linux.

```
app.put('/route', function(req, res){
    req.on('end', function () {  
      var child;      
      var values        = req.body;
      var shellScrpt    = " python /MyPython.py '"
      var shellScrptVar = JSON.stringify(values) + "' " ;  

      child = childProcess.exec(shellScrpt+shellScrptVar, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
         if (error) {
           console.log(error.stack);
         }
         console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);  
      });

      res.end();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved without using additional require:

```
  var pwdir         = path.resolve(process.cwd(),"../ParentWorkingDir")
  var shellScrpt    = " python "+ pwdir +"/MyPython.py '"
```